# Canvas Progress Circles in FireFox

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm working with this [codepen example](http://codepen.io/agrayson/pen/aAeCB) that uses canvas to create progress circles:

It works great in Chrome and Safari, but only shows black circles in FireFox. I'm not too familiar with canvas so I'm looking for some help / tips on how to get working in Firefox.

Where can I start? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to use a hash symbol for the color values:

```
canvas.strokeStyle = '#' + color;
```

this will fix the problem ad-hoc but just make sure the color values are with a prefixed hash-symbol when you pass them. Chrome is more flexible in this sense than Firefox which is why it works there.

**[Modified pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hgDKH)**

Hope this helps!